# ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated PipeLine throws javascript error

Tags: javascript, iis-7.5, asp.net-3.5, integrated-pipeline-mode

I had developed a `ASP.NET` application using `.NET 3.5 framework` and deployed in the `IIS` in application pool `DefaultAppPool`.

[image]

**Code:**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Sample.sample"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>Test</title>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR">
        <meta content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1" name="CODE_LANGUAGE">
        <meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript">
        <meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="vs_targetSchema">
    </HEAD>
    <body onload="document.frmTest.btnAdd.focus();">
        <form id="frmTest" method="post" runat="server">
            <input tabIndex="9" type="button" value="Add" name="btnAdd">
        </form>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

It is running without any issues for past 2 years.

Now, I have changed the application pool from `DefaultAppPool` to `ASP.NET v4.0 Integrated Pipeline` mode in `IIS`.

[image]

The application throws the error

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'btnAdd' of undefined or null reference
```

[image]
**Note:** I have revert the application pool to `DefaultAppPool`, the application runs without any error.

What is the cause for this error? Is there any setting to be changed to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to instead use

```
document.forms['frmTest'].btnAdd.focus();
```

Or specify  name attribute  to the form element as below:

```
<form method="post" action="Default" name="frmTest">
```

When you are changing the framework version, .net is probably adding additional attributes to the aspx page and hence the code seems to work with the default app pool .net framework 2.0

**Update:**

The reason is, In `ASP.NET v4.0` the `name` attribute for `form` tag is not generated while rendering the page.

We can fix this by addding below setting in the `<system.web>` tag in the application's `web.config` file

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" />
```

Comment: Thanks.. The reason is that, In `ASP.NET v4.0` the `name` attribute for `form` tag is not generating. Is there any workaround or settings in web config file to fix this error, without changing the code. Because I need to change in many files.